# How to select the audio source while recording a video with flutter camera plugin

Tags: flutter, android-camera, recording, ios-camera

I need to play a playback in my Flutter app while recording a video with audio. To prevent the playback from being heard on the recorded video, I want the user to use headphones.
Unfortunately, some headphones microphones are awful, so I want to give the user the option to select the microphone freely, but the playback should always be played on the headphones. Is it possible to change the audio source in a flutter? And is it possible to control audio input and output separately?
If this is not yet possible in Flutter, does anyone have a solution how to achieve this natively in Kotlin and Swift?